# building a platform for reusing mathoverflow content

Tags: discussion, policy

I'm working together with PlanetMath contributor Raymond Puzio on a proposal that would improve the PlanetMath platform, making it useful for remixing contents from MathOverflow, math.stackexchange.com and other places around the web to produce mathematics textbooks -- for use on PlanetMath, and for export to places like [Wikibooks](http://en.wikibooks.org).  I thought this would be of interest to the community here, and I invite your feedback on **[the proposal](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Grants%3aIdeaLab/PlanetMath_Books_Project)**, as well as your endorsement (if you feel so inclined).  Any comments prior to the Sept. 30, 2013 deadline will be particularly useful!

I'm particularly interested in any policy-level implications or ramifications.  You use the same license here as we do on PlanetMath, so that won't be an issue, but if there are other things we need to be aware of (e.g. related to crawling the site) please advise.

Comment: ([Link to corresponding meta.math.SE thread](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/11084/264))

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Sounds interesting. Be aware that the Stack Exchange Creative Commons license specifies the manner in which attribution should be made. (See the [Terms of Service](http://stackexchange.com/legal).)

It's best not to scrape MathOverflow directly, but rather to use the Stack Exchange API. It's a relatively well designed JSON API, with a few quirks. I'm happy to answer questions via email about it, for people interacting with the MathOverflow content.

Comment: Thanks Scott, if you could add this as an endorsement on the proposal page, that would could tip the balance in favor of us getting funded to do this.

Comment: would/could I guess... division by ''possible''.